# When I want to make a draggable div I couldn't avoid selecting neighboured text

Tags: javascript, html

I am a JS beginner.
I have made a draggable `<div>`. When I drag it, it will select one or two words near the `<div>` or glint with the blue select box (see the code-snippet below).

It bothers the experience feeling a little. What I want most is to keep other normal words being selected when dragging dhe `<div>`.

Please help me optimize the code or tell me if there is any syntax mistake.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
  eventFunc.addEventListener(parent, 'mousedown', dragItem);
}

function dragItem(ev) {
  ev = ev || window.event;
  var element = eventFunc.target(ev);
  var spaceX = ev.clientX - element.offsetLeft,
    spaceY = ev.clientY - element.offsetTop,
    maxX = (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth) - element.offsetWidth,
    maxY = (document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight) - element.offsetHeight;
  document.onmousemove = function(ev) {
    ev = ev || window.event;
    eventFunc.stopPropagation(ev);
    element.style.left = (ev.clientX - spaceX) + 'px';
    element.style.top = (ev.clientY - spaceY) + 'px';
    if (element.offsetLeft < 0) {
      element.style.left = 0;
    } else if (element.offsetLeft > maxX) {
      element.style.left = maxX + 'px'
    }
    if (element.offsetTop < 0) {
      element.style.top = 0;
    } else if (element.offsetTop > maxY) {
      element.style.top = maxY + 'px'
    }
  }
  document.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    document.onmouseup = null;
  }
}
var eventFunc = {
  addEventListener: function(element, type, func) {
    if (addEventListener) {
      element.addEventListener(type, func, false);
    } else if (attachEvent) {
      element.attachEvent('on' + type, func);
    } else {
      element['on' + type] = func;
    }
  },
  target: function(ev) {
    return ev.target || ev.srcElement;
  },
  stopPropagation: function(ev) {
    if (ev.stopPropagation) {
      ev.stopPropagation();
    } else {
      ev.cancelBubble = true;
    }
  },
  preventDefault: function(ev) {
    if (ev.preventDefault) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    } else {
      ev.returnValue = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: all-scroll;
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 35px/35px'Segoe UI', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #ccc;
}
#children {
  text-align: left;
  color: initial;
  font: initial;
  cursor: auto;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
Outside Words
<div id="parent">
  <div id="children">I'm The Children Element. I'm The Children Element. I'm The Children Element. I'm The Children Element. I'm The Children Element. I'm The Children Element. I'm The Children Element. I'm The Children Element. I'm The Children Element.</div>
  DRAG ME
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe you could make the text unselectable with css?

Comment: @verjas yep it looks like another solution thx!

Answer (score 0):

inside your `dragItem` function.... add the following line...

```
function dragItem(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault()
}
```

[edit (fulfilling the rest of the question)]

To select contents of any piece of content... you can use this function...

```
function selectNode(el) {
  var range = document.createRange()
  range.selectNodeContents(el)
  var sel = window.getSelection()
  sel.removeAllRanges()
  sel.addRange(range)
}
```

// use it by passing in a node

```
selectNode(document.getElementById('parent'))
```